# JWT headers with Gatling Post Request

Tags: scala, jwt, gatling

I want to include a JWT header with my Gatling POST request.

I am doing something like this:

```
val R1= scenario("Scenario")
.feed(idFeeder)
.header("", "",
Jwt.sha256(requestBody), "", "", "")))
   .body(
    StringBody(session => requestBody.replace(
      "0000000000",
      session("id").as[String]
    ))
  ).asJSON
```

Where "id" is a session attribute which contains a randomly generated id to be added to the requestBody.
How can I obtain the id substituted request body in Jwt.sha256(requestBody) which send the request body to the JWT class to get the hash of it (Which should be included in the JWT header)

**Jwt.sha256() requires a String and returns a URL encode of the string**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Jwt.sha256()` takes a string body and returns some String token then its just like with body:

```
.header(
  "HeaderName",
  session => Jwt.sha256(requestBody.replace("0000000000", session("id").as[String]))
)
```

Comment: Jwt.sha256() requires a String and returns a URL encode of the string.